# Setting up Hadoop with Cloudera Manager in Pseudo Distributed mode - Datanode won't start

Tags: hadoop, cloudera, cloudera-manager

I'm trying to set up a single node cluster using Cloudera Manager, here's the latest problem I'm having.

When I try to start all services, HDFS won't start, it appears to be a problem with the Datanode - the fatal error message it gives is

```
Initialization failed for block pool Block pool BP-1896453393-127.0.1.1-1382183730690 (storage id DS-185043233-127.0.1.1-50010-1382183775494) service to Hadoop1/127.0.1.1:8022
org.apache.hadoop.ipc.RemoteException(org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.protocol.DisallowedDatanodeException): Datanode denied communication with namenode: DatanodeRegistration(127.0.0.1, storageID=DS-185043233-127.0.1.1-50010-1382183775494, infoPort=50075, ipcPort=50020, storageInfo=lv=-40;cid=cluster25;nsid=1577346304;c=0)
at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.blockmanagement.DatanodeManager.registerDatanode(DatanodeManager.java:656)
at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.FSNamesystem.registerDatanode(FSNamesystem.java:3495)
at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.NameNodeRpcServer.registerDatanode(NameNodeRpcServer.java:899)
at 
...
```

When I run the host inspector, it gives the following warning:

```
The following errors were found while checking /etc/hosts...

The hostname Hadoop1 maps to 127.0.1.1 in /etc/hosts. 
This setting, typically found in Debian and Ubuntu environments, typically causes issues. 
We recommend either using the standard loopback address (127.0.0.1) or specifying the appropriate IP address for your host.
```

From googling, it seems the problem is related to the IP address used, and the root of the problem might be in my /etc/hosts file, which looks like this.

```
127.0.0.1   localhost
127.0.1.1   Hadoop1

# The following lines are desirable for IPv6 capable hosts
::1     ip6-localhost ip6-loopback
fe00::0 ip6-localnet
ff00::0 ip6-mcastprefix
ff02::1 ip6-allnodes
ff02::2 ip6-allrouters
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Got this sorted, instead of using 127.0.1.1 in the /etc/hosts file I used the IP address of the machine which is in the Point-to-Point section of ifconfig.

The output of ifconfig will have a section like

```
ppp0      Link encap:Point-to-Point Protocol  
          inet addr:xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx  P-t-P:xx.xx.xx.xx  Mask:255.255.255.255
          UP POINTOPOINT RUNNING NOARP MULTICAST  MTU:1440  Metric:1
          RX packets:800950 errors:1 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:454479 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:3 
          RX bytes:1115444967 (1.1 GB)  TX bytes:32007110 (32.0 MB)
```

Take the inet addr: ip from this.

Or run

```
ifconfig | grep P-t-P
```

for the exact line.